# How to access <ui:inputTextArea in helper.js for a component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

In my component, I have `ui:inputtextarea` field defined as below

```
<ui:inputTextArea aura:id="generatedLinks" label="Links"  value="" rows="5" />
```

In my controller, I'm trying to call `getElement` method, but it's throwing an error. 
Here is how I'm accessing `getElement`

```
var linksTA = cmp.find("generatedLinks").getElement();
```

What am I doing wrong ?
Any guidance??

Comment: Hi @salesforce, What is the error you getting?

Comment: Uncaught Action failed: c:FilesExplorer$controller$generateEMailLinks [cmp.find(...).getElement is not a function]

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with any clarifications. That is not what comments are for.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you want to access value inside the inputTextArea. You can do that by accessing value attribute in your component.

Thus your code will be:

```
var linksTA = cmp.find("generatedLinks").get("v.value");
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I need to have access to the textarea html element in helper js file , so i can programmatically select all the text in the text area box.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the value to an attribute and it will update dynamically when the user changes the value like so

AURA

```
<aura:attribute name="generatedLinksVal" type="String" default=""/>
<ui:inputTextArea aura:id="generatedLinks" label="Links"  value="{!v.generatedLinksVal}" rows="5" />
```

JS

```
cmp.get("v.generatedLinksVal");
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the aura:id of your component is unique. If you have multiple components with the sames aura:id, `component.find()` will return an array. In that case, you'll see the error you mentioned.